# WPF UserControl OnGotFocus/OnLostFocus

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I've created a WPF UserControl with some TextBoxes, but if I click into a TextBox on it, the OnGotFocus of the UserControl is not called.

How can I get it? Or what is the best practice in that situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OnGotFocus method is fired in response to the GotFocus routed event that have the bubbling routing strategy. This method is not fired because the corresponding event is processed at the embedded child control level.

You can check GotFocus/LostFocus events. These event should be fired for your TextBox and UserControl as well.